# Как вставить ссылку в строку таблицы?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Всем привет!
Как можно вставить ссылку в строку таблицы ну или еще какие есть варианты?
Что бы можно было нажать в любом месте строки и что было понятно что это ссылка.

```css
table {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}
tr {
background: #2F4F4F;
}
.left {
  padding: 2px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
}
.right {
  padding: 2px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 12pt;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="left">Имя:</td>
    <td class="right">Вася</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="left">Имя:</td>
    <td class="right">Петя</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Два вопроса. Почему именно так, а не JS? И что значит _"... что было понятно что это ссылка."_ Это как? Нативные ссылки подчёркнуты, но повсеместно народ стилизует, как заблагорассудится. Только `cursor: pointer`?

Comment: можно еще на `hover` менять цвет ячейки

Comment: @UModeL надо именно html+css. что бы отображался адрес ссылки. Нашел выход с помощью <div> позже скину решение. всем спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```css
table {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}

tr {
  background: #2F4F4F;
}

.left {
  padding: 2px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
}

.right {
  padding: 2px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 12pt;
}

td a {
  color: #fdc073;
  transition: color 0.1s linear;
}

td a:hover {
  color: #e96861;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="left">Имя:</td>
    <td class="right">Фамилия: </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="left">
      <a href="https://css-tricks.com/">Вася</a>
    </td>
    <td class="right">Иванов</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Или так

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.table__item {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

.table__a {
  color: inherit;
  z-index: 1;
}

.table__a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: background-color 0.1s linear;
}

.table__a:hover::before {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table__item">
   <a class="table__a" href="https://css-tricks.com/">Ссылкаdsad asdsa das asd as</a>
  </div>
  <div class="table__item">
    Ячейка таблицы
  </div>
  <div class="table__item">
    Ячейка таблицы
  </div>
  <div class="table__item">
    Ячейка таблицы
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ссылка работает только по тексту, а нужно по всей области строчки.

Comment: @JonBrasers да, я неправильно понял вопрос

Comment: тоже не то, я нашел решение и дал ответ. спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так. Может кому пригодится, оставдю тут

```css
a { text-decoration: none; }
a:visited { text-decoration: none; } 
a:active { text-decoration: none; }
.tbl {
    width: 200px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 8px 0 0 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    Justify-content: center;
    background: #444;
}
.left{
    padding: 5px 8px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100px;
}
.right{
    padding: 5px 8px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a href="/user/id_1">
  <div class="tbl">
    <div class="left">Имя:</div>
    <div class="right">Васек</div>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="/user/id_2">
  <div class="tbl">
    <div class="left">Имя:</div>
    <div class="right">Петька</div>
  </div>
</a>
```